# by the way of our thinking Vs. by the way we think

Tags: expressions

Is it correct to say

> Everything changes by the way of our thinking.

or should I say:

> Everything changes by the way we think.

And how different are they in meaning?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use 'Everything is changed by the way we think.'

How things affect us is important to us, and *seeing things in a different light* can have a profound effect upon us, though external factors may not immediately improve (or, I suppose, deteriorate). We might also say, on receiving new information or insight, 'That puts a different complexion on things.'